# Fluent Validation - Multiple error messages according to query result

Tags: c#, validation, fluent

I am trying to write validation rule for multiple string properties, to check whether they are unique.
so i made validator to check it.
`_service` method returns list of error codes, that correspond with properties which are not unique.
Now how can I get response message **or several** in accordance with returned result codes?

```
RuleFor(x => x.User)
    .MustAsync(async (q, context, token) =>
    {
        var errors = await _service.CheckUserNameEmailExistsAsync(q.User.UserName, q.User.Email, token);
         return !errors.Any();
     }).WithMessage(...);
```

Comment: What is `errors` exactly? I'd make a sub-validator for User. Then you can check uniqueness of each of it's properties and add a failure to the context if appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go this way:
Create a local variable of your type, and put the result there. And in "WithMessage" refer to it and display the message you need.

example:

```
            SomeType errors;

            RuleFor(x => x.User)
                .MustAsync(async (q, context, token) =>
                {
                    errors = await _service.CheckUserNameEmailExistsAsync(q.User.UserName, q.User.Email, token);
                    return !errors.Any();
                }).WithMessage((_) => 
                {
                    if (errors....)
                        return "some message";
                    else if (errors...)
                        return "other some message";
                    else
                        return "another some message";
                });
```